# Skipar um argumento opcional dentre vários no Python

Tags: python

No seguinte código:

```
 def FuncEx(hashTag, lang="pt-br", pages=3):
        sel.get(f"A hashtag {hashTag}, na linguagem {lang}, no total de {pages} páginas.")
```

Como eu poderia fazer caso quisesse passar apenas oo parâmetros `hashTag` e `pages`, deixando o `lang` como default?

Tentei algo como:

```
FuncEx("politica", null, 2)
```

Mas não rolou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ou você chama a função com os argumentos em ordem, ou coloca o nome dos argumentos na hora de chamar.  No caso, se quiser deixar o defaul de  `lang` e mandar `pages`, basta fazer:

`FuncEx("politica", pages=2)`

Pronto - como não foi passado nem um segundo argumento posicional, nem um argumento como nome `lang`, o valor padrão vai ser usado.